# Webforms Login-Control and IE 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, authentication, webforms

The Webforms Login Control has two different textbox widths in IE10?
Anyone has a workaround for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found out 2 solutions:

1. setting the input css style:

   ```
   input
   {
       width: 150px !important;
   }
   ```
2. convert to itemtemplate and set the width property of the textboxes